# Access violation reading location when using recursion?

Tags: c++, try-catch, access-violation

The below code is used as part of a trade function where a list of properties is displayed and the used types in the properties they want to trade.

The 'Access violation reading location error' occurs on the propertyName variable when the user has entered a property that doesn't exist (the catch block is run) and then enters a valid property.

I don't understand why it is throwing this error, I'm guessing it's something I've done in the catch block with the getline or the recursion I can't work it out.

**player trade function**

```
void player::trade(player &tradePlayer){
    ***

    //code extract
    cout << "What properties would you like from " << tradePlayer.getPlayerName() << " ? (Enter done when finished selecting)" << endl;
    string propertyName;
    vector<properties> theirProperties; 
    int theirCash;
    ws(cin);
    getline(cin, propertyName); //gets property name
    while (propertyName != "done") {
        theirProperties.push_back(tradePlayer.getOwnedProperty(propertyName));
        getline(cin, propertyName); **Access violation appears here**
    }

    ***
```

**player class - getOwnedProperty()**

```
class player
{
public:

***
    //code extract
    properties &getOwnedProperty(string name) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < ownedProperties.size(); i++) {
                if (ownedProperties.at(i).getProperty() == name) {
                    return ownedProperties.at(i);
                }
            }
            throw exception();
        }
        catch (exception){
            cout << "Property name not recognised! Try again." << endl;
            ws(cin);
            getline(cin, name);
            getOwnedProperty(name);
        }

    }

***

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is thrown because your loop doesn't find any match with its if() statement in your getOwnedProperty() function. It is a mistake to compare string values with == operator, so you should use string::compare() method. Read about how to use it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdstringcompare-in-c/

Comment: If the if() statement fails to find a match in the ownedProperty function an exception is thrown, and then the catch block is run containing the recursion. This is done till the user enters a property that does match the if() statement. Is there something I'm missing with my logic in using the recursion?

Comment: Generally, recursion is not encouraged unless really useful in terms of simplicity and code-clarity. Second, exception handling is also costly in terms of performance, so you should use it really to handle exceptional error states in your program. Therefore, I really advise you to restructure your code by avoiding exceptions and recursion, and favoring a do-while loop in this particular case.